# Como convertir el formato de la fecha y hora consultada desde Internet?

Tags: java, android

Como verán en la imagen a continuación, consulto desde Internet la fecha y hora, todo va bien incluso con la zona horaria, el problema es que el nombre del **Mes** y del **Día** de la semana vienen en inglés, como podría cambiarlos a español y eliminar ese dato que dice **"GMT-0500"**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Aquí el código que realiza la consulta de la fecha y hora:**

```
public void GetTime(){
        try {
            TimeTCPClient client = new TimeTCPClient();
            try {
                // Set timeout of 60 seconds
                client.setDefaultTimeout(60000);
                // Connecting to time server
                // Other time servers can be found at : http://tf.nist.gov/tf-cgi/servers.cgi#
                // Make sure that your program NEVER queries a server more frequently than once every 4 seconds
                client.connect("time.nist.gov");
                //System.out.println(client.getDate());
                Hora.setText("Ultima Actualización el "+client.getDate().toString().trim());
            } finally {
                client.disconnect();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, o si saben otro método también se los agradecería.
¡Gracias!

Comment: Verifica que el idioma del dispositivo sea en español y que la zona horaria este en la zona de tu localizacion.

Comment: Agrega que realiza el metodo client.getDate()
  checho

Comment: Hola Jorge, lo que realiza es lo que esta en la imagen, eso es lo que trae de la consulta desde Internet y lo muestro en ese `TextView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay que darle formato con el método SimpleDateFormat, de esta forma:

```
private String getDate() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMMM yyyy  HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
        Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }
```

`Locale.getDefault()` da los valores en el idioma que tenga el dispositivo.
El patrón de fecha hay varios, ejemplos: `EE` = mar `EEEE` = martes `d` = 1 `dd` = 01 `hh:mm a` = 10:10 AM ... Mas info: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Entonces lo que se debe hacer primero es crear un`Date` personalizado y luego se lo paso al `client` y ahí si tomara la fecha y hora tal como se lo especifique? Si es así o me equivoco?

Comment: Ya lo implemente y funciono a la perfección, así quedo: `SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
                    String result = dateformat.format(client.getDate());
                    Hora.setText("Ultima Actualización el "+result);` **Muchísimas Gracias @armen**